# Configure VS Code to execute Python script only if there are no linter errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VS Code to only execute a python script if there are no linter errors? I am using Python 3.9.0 and VS Code 1.49.0. Linter is mypy (mypy-0.790, mypy-extensions-0.4.3, typed-ast-1.4.1, typing-extensions-3.7.4.3). OS is Windows 10, version 2004.

Currently, while linter reports problems correctly (*incompatible type*, based on type hints, for instance), pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> still runs the code (which crashes, as the linter is correct). I would like VS Code to only proceed to the "Run" step if the linter output has no errors, as the time taken to execute a script with linter errors is basically a waste of time.

How can this be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new task. If you don't already have a `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder (or you don't have a `.vscode` folder), you can press F1 and run "Tasks: Configure Task", then select "Create tasks.json file from template". Select "Others" from the list of templates. It should generate a file that looks like this:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

Change the label to "lint" (or any other label that suits your fancy), and change the command to "mypy <directories or files>". For more information on the mypy command, refer to [the docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html).

If you *do* already have a `tasks.json` file, just copy the part inside the tasks array into your tasks array and make the same changes.

Then, open your `launch.json` and add the following line into whichever configuration(s) you're using.

```json
"preLaunchTask": "lint",
```

If the task fails, you'll see a dialogue box pop up saying

> The preLaunchTask 'lint' terminated with exit code 1.

and asking if you want to "Debug Anyway", Show Errors", or "Abort". There'll also be a checkbox to have VS Code remember your choice in your settings (if you'd like to set this before the first time you get an error, the setting is named `debug.onTaskErrors`).

Additional resources:
[Tasks Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)
[Debugging Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)
[Description of `debug.onTaskErrors`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings:%7E:text=%22debug.onTaskErrors%22%3A%20%22prompt%22%2C)